# Python converting a split function back

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

What I want my answer to look like: `Hello World`

Notice that it is not a string so it does not have apostrophes around it

```
m = 'Hello World'
w = m.split()
for final in w:
    (final = ??, end = ' ')
Hello World
```

The code i want looks very similar to this, I just forgot what to put for final and end

Comment: So you don't want your final answer to be a string?

Comment: Hmm. `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. A string would make more sense

Comment: What do you mean that `Hello World` is not a string? So what is that, if not string?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what the question is, but I'll at least say something relevant.

```
>>> m = 'Hello World'
>>> w = m.split()
>>> n = ' '.join(w)
>>> print(n)
Hello World
```

Here, `'Hello World'` is split on the spaces, so you just have to join the pieces with spaces.